# Second digit is in range 1 through 5 inclusive meaning?

Tags: java

What does second digit is in range 1 through 5 inclusive means?

What does inclusive mean?

Does it mean this:

```
return x >= 1 && x <= 5;
```

Or

```
return x > 1 && x < 5;
```

Comment: Google [`inclusive`](https://www.google.com/search?q=inclusive) and it says: *with the inclusion of the extreme limits stated*. So `1` and `5` (the stated extreme limits) are included.

Answer (score 6):

It means the first, as in it includes the values `1` and `5`.

```
 x >= 1 && x <= 5
```

is `true` when `x` is any of `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `5`. While

```
 x > 1 && x < 5
```

is `true` when `x` is `2`, `3` or `4` (and does not **include** `1` or `5`).

Comment: Thanks Elliot Frisch. Is it weird to say thanks on this website? I notice not a lot of people say thanks.

Comment: It isn't generally considered constructive, instead [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and remember to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which indicates your question is answered (and rewards the accepted answerer).

Comment: so the reverse of inclusive is exclusive?